# Python subprocess behaves differently across distributions

Tags: python, ubuntu, popen

I've written a small python script to act as a LSB compliant init script for an Apache Tomcat service. I've done this script and initial tests on my work laptop which runs openSUSE; The actual deployment is to be made on Ubuntu Server (no jokes about it please, I also feel sad about it).

While the script works perfectly under openSUSE (python 2.7.3), in Ubuntu it's behavior is different (also python 2.7.3)...

When I perform the subprocess.Popen call, in openSUSE it opens the process and then I capture the .pid to a 'control' file...

In Ubuntu, the very same script, the subprocess.Popen call opens two process, one starting with '/usr/bin -c java (...)' and then another 'java (...)'. This is really annoying has the PID written is the one from the /bin/sh...

This is my first time working with Ubuntu Server and though I'm already planning to migrate everything to RHEL (where this non-sense doesn't happen also), I'm still interested in knowing why this happens in Ubuntu and potential ways to dodge around it...

The start function is this one

```
def start():
    set_user()
    with open(CATALINA_OUT, "a") as log:
        tomcat = subprocess.Popen(TOMCAT_CMD + 'start', shell=True, stdout=log, stderr=log)
    write_pidfile(tomcat.pid)

def set_user():
    os.setgid(int(TOMCAT_GID))
    os.setuid(int(TOMCAT_UID))
```

Comment: This is impossible to answer without seeing some code.

Comment: I've added the function I use to start and the set_user() for reference. start() does behave differently in openSUSE and Ubuntu (openSUSE 12.3 vs Ubuntu 12.04).

Comment: Are you using the same version of Tomcat on both OSes? Sometimes it's the simplest of things that catch us off guard...

Comment: I don't believe it's a Tomcat issue, but yes, it's the same version of Tomcat (latest upstream binary release, 7.0.39).

Comment: If you want to skip the shell, pass `shell=False` to `Popen`. That gives more control over how many processes are started.

Comment: Where and how is `TOMCAT_CMD` defined?

Comment: `/usr/bin -c java` makes no sense, do you mean `/bin/sh -c java`? Then yes the fix would be `shell=False` and/or making sure `TOMCAT_CMD` points where you want it to.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `TOMCAT_CMD` is basically `java -whatever` it seems likely that `/usr/bin/java` is just (some variant of) Java on most platforms, but a shell script implementing some detail of Debian Java policy on Ubuntu, before `exec`:ing the system's preferred Java binary with the correct parameters. For what it's worth, the latter in general is a good thing because it makes it much easier to switch from one Java implementation to another, but if you only care about one particular implementation, then you can link directly to that implementation's binary in `TOMCAT_CMD` (and/or reimplement the policy in Python if you want to be fully Debian-compliant and cannot live with the shell script).

Comment: Thanks; You are right about TOMCAT_CMD, that's the java + args. The /usr/bin/java is a symlink to /etc/alternatives/java which symlinks to openjdk-7-jre. Looks pretty normal...

I've actually fixed it... The difference is that openSUSE uses bash as default and Ubuntu uses sh. So on the subprocess.Popen I add 'executable=/bin/bash', it behaves the same way as in openSUSE. That seems to be the difference. Thanks for your reply, indirectly it led me to finding the answer.